# UI5 application using local proxy throws URN error

Tags: odata, sapui5

I followed [this tutorial](https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/1809.000/en-US/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e.html) to create local proxy using node.js library. I got rid of the CORS problem, but I have another problem and it is this one:

[image]

I suspect that the problem is caused by defining the data source's uri like this:

```
"dataSources": {
    "Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV": {
        "uri": "localhost:8081/http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is cause by "localhost:8081/" prefix in the URI, but I do not know how to get rid of the problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to set port from which the app runs. I run the app in personal WebIDE so my port in 'proxy.js' file is '58513'. Also it is necessary to add 'http://' as a prefix to the data source uri. So my manifest looks like this:

```
    "dataSources": {
       "Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV": {
           "uri": "http://localhost:58513/http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV",
           "type": "OData",
           "settings": {
               "odataVersion": "2.0",
               "localUri": "localService/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/metadata.xml"
           }
       }
   }
```

However, I am now getting this error which I am not able to resolve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an authentication problem. Did you try to add user and password in the request?

```
 "uri": "http://localhost:58513/http://user:password@your.server:8080/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV"
```